# epoch conversion off by 1 second

Tags: oracle, epoch

```
select from_tz(
         cast(
           to_date('1970-01-01 00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24')
             + (1536698971759)/1000/60/60/24
           as timestamp
         ),
         'GMT'
       ) at time zone 'US/Eastern'
from   dual;
```

yields:

```
11-SEP-18 04.49.32.000000 PM US/EASTERN
```

Yet if you plug `1536698971759` into any online converter you will see the # of seconds is actually 3**1**, not 3**2**.

What is wrong?

Comment: I think the select statement is rounding off the milliseconds, i.e. 759 ms and hence increasing the seconds by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem with implicit rounding. `DATE` data type (due to `TO_DATE()`) does not support fractional seconds, thus 31.759 is rounded to 32.

Try this one:

```
SELECT
   (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + 1536698971759/1000 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'
FROM dual;
```

or `(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(1536698971759/1000, 'SECOND')) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'` if you prefer

```
yields: 11.09.2018 16:49:31.759000000 -04:00
```